# Определять AJAX - запрос на конкретной странице

Tags: php, ajax

Есть условие по которому мы определяем страницу с ajax-запросом. Как дополнить условие, чтобы оно выполнялось только на конкретной странице с которой идёт запрос? Например только с `www.xxx.ru/null/lol.php`:

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В суперглобальной переменной `$_SERVER` есть ключ `HTTP_REFERER`. Им можно воспользоваться для решения задачи.

Например вот:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.xxx.ru/null/lol.php') {echo 'Нужная страница';}
```

Документацию по содержимому переменной можно найти [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php).